# MongoDB can not start by the command `service mongod start`

Tags: mongodb

when i run the command `sudo service mongod start` the MongoDB cannot start and when i run the service mongod status it shows it has not been started, and the log shows:

```
2018-07-05T14:32:03.595+0800 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15656 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=iZbp1ik57sceo226yjpivxZ
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0-rc7
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7230641bb09b1ceb04c3135cf83a5044c4838906
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-07-05T14:32:03.605+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=488M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1530772324:204155][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1530772324:204155][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1530772324:204458][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1530772324:204458][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1530772324:204610][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1530772324:204610][15656:0x7fb5cb734a00], wiredtiger_open: /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] 13: Permission denied
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 194
2018-07-05T14:32:04.204+0800 F -        [initandlisten]
***aborting after fassert() failure
```

but when i tried `mongod --auth -f /etc/mongod.conf` the server can start and when visit the log file it shows that:

```
2018-07-05T14:35:34.228+0800 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-07-05T14:35:34.239+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15665 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=iZbp1ik57sceo226yjpivxZ
2018-07-05T14:35:34.239+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0-rc7
2018-07-05T14:35:34.239+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 7230641bb09b1ceb04c3135cf83a5044c4838906
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-07-05T14:35:34.240+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=488M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-07-05T14:35:35.005+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1530772535:5560][15665:0x7f0ab9512a00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 18/8960
2018-07-05T14:35:35.113+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1530772535:113878][15665:0x7f0ab9512a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 18 through 19
2018-07-05T14:35:35.179+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1530772535:179582][15665:0x7f0ab9512a00], txn-recover: Recovering log 19 through 19
2018-07-05T14:35:35.248+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1530772535:248647][15665:0x7f0ab9512a00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2018-07-05T14:35:35.283+0800 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2018-07-05T14:35:35.311+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-07-05T14:35:35.311+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 7856 processes, 65535 files. Number of processes should be at least 32767.5 : 0.5 times number of files.
2018-07-05T14:35:35.312+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-07-05T14:35:35.336+0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2018-07-05T14:35:35.337+0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

and the whole config file is as below:

```
# mongod.conf
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
journal:
  enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

So, what is the matter with it? why the first method can not run it but the second method can start it?

Comment: Could you share your ` /etc/mongod.conf`?

Comment: I have edit the question and added the config file in the end.

Comment: first check your mongod status using service mongod status. is active or dead ?

Comment: Please do not use images. They are hard to read on mobile devices and impossible to copy & paste and stuff. ;) Instead, add a code block.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana  I check the status, the status is dead and shows failed

Comment: OS? Looks like you started `mongod` as a different user (most likely `root` via `sudo`) at least once.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Sorry, i hava changed the image to code block and the system is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try `[sudo] chown mongodb.mongodb  -R /var/lib/mongodb && chown mongodb.mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log && service mongod start`. And _please_ use the search. This question was answered some million times.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you!

Comment: Try rm -f /var/lock/subsys/mongod and rm -f /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock then restart mongod service

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [@Markus W Mahlberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296707/markus-w-mahlberg), and after run these command, the problem has been solved.

```sh
[sudo] chown mongodb.mongodb -R /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I met the same issue, but under window 10. The `chown mongodb.mongodb -R /var/lib/mongodb` returned `chown: invalid user: ‘mongodb.mongodb’`.

Comment: @Leo.W Don’t use Windows since about 15 years. Maybe someone else can help. Please ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com AFTER using the search function. ;)

Comment: Should be a colon not a period, of course. See the man page for chown.

Comment: there is are typos in the answer above. please change the command to
`sudo chown mongodb:mongodb -R /var/lib/mongd` note the `:` in `mongodb:mongodb` and the username `mongodb` not `mongod`

Answer (score 7):

If you ran the command `mongod` as root on the server while testing your configuration file, as in:

```
$ mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

The mongo server will generate the mongo.lock file and the WiredTiger.lock files and further files in the mongodb folder with root:root ownership as in:

```
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      36864 Nov 25 12:03 index-95--8062076833940689665.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      45056 Nov 25 12:03 index-96--8062076833940689665.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      36864 Nov 25 12:03 index-99--8062076833940689665.wt
drwx------  2 mongodb mongodb       4096 Nov 25 15:23 journal/
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      45056 Nov 25 15:32 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-------  1 root    root             0 Nov 25 15:32 mongod.lock
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb      36864 Nov 25 15:32 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb        114 Oct 17 17:41 storage.bson
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb         44 Oct 17 17:41 WiredTiger
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb       4096 Nov 25 15:32 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-------  1 root    root            21 Nov 25 15:22 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb       1201 Nov 25 15:32 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb     188416 Nov 25 15:32 WiredTiger.wt
```

The service is most likely configured to run `mongod` with the `mongodb` user. which will not have permission to remove, or overwrite the `WiredTiger.lock` nor the `mongod.lock` or any other file that were created when `mongod` was running using the `root` user. In the case above the `/var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle`

The solution is to reset the ownership of all the files in the folder in the case above the `/var/lib/mongodb/` folder to the mongodb user:

```
$ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: You were right about the ownership issue and realized this happens when we start mongod process as a user (with sudo). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a mac OS

1. Browse to the data directory you configured when installing mongodb. For ex: data/db where the mongod.lock and WiredTiger.lock are present
2. sudo chown -R {username}:{groupname} /data/db
3. Make sure you have stopped any mongo processes
4. run 'mongod' command

You should now see the prompt which is now ready to accept connections.